# How to compute two different dates using Datepicker Dialog as a Button

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm having a problem on computing two different dates using Datepicker Dialog as a Button. Because my project cannot resolve the method getTimeInMillis(). And I want the result to be computed on the number of customers. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
long diff = to.getTimeInMillis() - from.getTimeInMillis();
String total = ""+passenger*diff;
```

Comment: what you want to achieve from these 2 dates - i.e Final output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, how to find duration between 2 dates

```
    public String differenceDuration(String date1, String date2) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(date1.replace("T"," "));
        d2 = format.parse(date2.replace("T"," "));

        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
        System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
        System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
        System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

        return ""+hoursDiff+"h "+diffMinutes+"m";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: always there to help